# Mysql query problem01

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]
[image]

I want to do a query that can display the average score for each country, in descending order. I wrote this code but doesn't work correctly

```
SELECT  AVG(`scores`), `country` 
 FROM scores , players 
 GROUP BY `country`
 ORDER BY AVG(`scores`) DESC
```

Can anyone help me on that? Thanks

Comment: You almost had it,add the  JOIN condition `on scores.username=players.username ` You will have problems when different countries have the same player,assuming this is indeed the foreign key

Comment: You need to use an `INNER JOIN users ON users.Username = scores.Username`

Comment: It would be better to post your table schema description instead of an external screenshot. Please add your `CREATE TABLE`scripts

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a JOIN condition, your scores and player table are not related, you should do something like this :

```
SELECT  AVG(scores.score), `country` 
 FROM scores 
 INNER JOIN players ON scores.username = players.username
 GROUP BY players.`country`
 ORDER BY AVG(scores.score) DESC
```

I fixed a few typos too, `scores`and `score`are two different things!

Comment: scores from all of the games are processed together; don't you want to split average scores by country and game?

Answer (score 0):

**Just another way of doing it**

```
SELECT AVG(score) as av,country 
FROM 
(SELECT country,score 
FROM players INNER JOIN scores ON players.Username=scores.Username 
ORDER BY country)t 
GROUP BY t.country order by av desc
```